# Sabre web-services DepartureWindow format

Tags: web-services, sabre

Do you know what's the format of the DepartureWindow parameter for sabre web-services' OTA_AirLowFareSearch call? Whatever I pass, it shows me an error.

This is the entire documentation for those parameters (I kid you not):

```
<!--"DepartureDateTime" represents the date and time of departure.-->
<DepartureDateTime>2004-11-22T15:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
<!--"DepartureWindow" represents a window of time to search prior and post departure.-->
<!--Example: JR.DFW/S-OYLAS22NOV1500‡ZRD09001700-->
<DepartureWindow>09001700</DepartureWindow>
```

I've already tryied passing the number of seconds since DepartureDateTime and a unix timestamp without success. The error message it's:

```
Error response received. The error was: INVALID TIME WINDOW IN  Z FIELDS
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must specify time within window in DepartureDateTime

```
 <ns1:DepartureDateTime>2009-01-03T15:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
 <ns1:DepartureWindow>11001559</ns1:DepartureWindow>
```

works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

also, you can use OriginDestinationInformation.TPA_Extensions.AlternateTime instead